# How do you programmatically look up dyno information from heroku in node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-api

My nodejs web application runs on a variable number/type of dynos.

Is there a way to get the dynos setup in node ?

Ex:

```
   dynos: {
       web: {
         standard-1x: 2,
       },
       worker: {
         standard-2x: 4
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the platform API. In particular, we represent the type and number of dynos setup for an application as a resource called "formation". You can see how to list your current formation information here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#formation-list